# Execute Function on click of googlemap marker

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function on the click of a googlemap marker. I have read several responses here but none worked for me. I get no response when the marker is clicked. Below is my googlemap code. The function testCase() isnt getting called. Note this code contains some JSP code which should be ignored.

```
var locations = [];

        <%
                for(Object t: posts)
                {
                    ReportModel md = (ReportModel) t;
                    String toSplit[] = md.getCaseLocation().split(",");

        %>

      locations [locations.length] = ['<%=md.getCategory()%>', <%=toSplit[0]%>, <%=toSplit[1]%>,<%=md.getCode()%>, 4];

        <%
                }
        %>
      console.log(locations);



    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.4549, 3.4246),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {

          testCase(locations[i][3]);
        }
      })(marker, i));


function testCase(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a listener to the marker:

```
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log('TEST CLICKED TO ENSURE THAT IT WORKS')
        testCase(locations[i][3])
    })
```

References:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure

Comment: Try putting the testCase function before locations assignation in your code.

Comment: the testCase is in another js file websocketshander.js. and its also called by other buttons which works well. its the markers giving problems

Comment: You need to load the testCase function, so it can be referenced by the listener and binded to the closure.

Comment: You can try putting all google maps inside `window.onload = function() {
 // put your code here
};`, so you can ensure the js file was loaded and the code can access the gobal function.